# Why www.example.com/index.php/my/path/here is processed by index.php?

Tags: php, apache, friendly-url

I am just curious, how is feature of apache is called that is directing requests like this

```
www.example.com/index.php/my/path/here
```

to a file index.php? At the first moment, you might think, that it would be correct if this request leads to 404 error page because there is no **folder** called index.php at the site root dir.

BTW, is there a possibility to turn off this Apache feature (if it is a feature) so that such requests really end up with 404?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't a URL rewrite feature. Or at least it doesn't *need* to be. See [AcceptPathInfo Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html):

> This directive controls whether
>   requests that contain trailing
>   pathname information that follows an
>   actual filename (or non-existent file
>   in an existing directory) will be
>   accepted or rejected. The trailing
>   pathname information can be made
>   available to scripts in the
>   `PATH_INFO` environment variable.
>
> For example, assume the location
>   /test/ points to a directory that
>   contains only the single file
>   `here.html`. Then requests for
>   `/test/here.html/more` and
>   `/test/nothere.html/more` both collect
>   `/more` as `PATH_INFO`.

It was originally a [CGI environment variable](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/env.html).

> - `PATH_INFO`
>
> The extra path information, as given
>   by the client. In other words, scripts
>   can be accessed by their virtual
>   pathname, followed by extra
>   information at the end of this path.
>   The extra information is sent as
>   `PATH_INFO`. This information should
>   be decoded by the server if it comes
>   from a URL before it is passed to the
>   CGI script.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [this link](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/search-engine-friendly-urls) for an explanation.

It is a method of passing information to the (in this case) `index.php` script *without* using a query string, which would be ignored by some search engines, hence the name of the article "Search Engine-Friendly URLs".

I can recommend the third method discussed in the article because it avoids strange looking URLS with `index.php` in the middle.

Comment: Thank you, it is a very interesting article.

Answer (score 1):

It's there that you can have a file like index.php check the PATH_INFO from the server and handle a whole tree of content.  While there's no way I know of to turn it off, you can simply have index.php check for a non-empty $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] and respond with a 404 code via the header() function.